# Files application crash while creating a new file

Tags: release-jolnir

Files application crash every time I want to create a new file.

I can create a directory, but while creating file application crash permanently.

Tried to change permissions to 777, but no results.

Any idea how to fix?

Currently I create new files using terminal "touch new-file.txt".

Edit: everything is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After today's update of Files application everything is working properly, I can create a new file.